# Duplicate a tab within a tab control

Tags: tabs, duplicates, filemaker

I have created a `tab control` and want each tab within it to have the same layout/formatting (but perhaps filtering the results or pulling results from different tables). The easiest way to do this would be to duplicate my first tab and then edit it, but strangely this doesn't appear as an option in the Tab Control Setup.

How can I duplicate a tab within a tab control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select all the contents of the first tab, copy, create a new tab, then paste.

It may make selecting the contents easier if you first lock the tab object, you can then drag-select without selecting the actual tab object itself.

Comment: thanks, that was my current work-around, but it is not that great a solution since I need to copy the contents in *exactly* the same place (even after grouping all the objects) - they need to be moved around until they are in the right place. It seems strange you can't just duplicate!

Comment: Use the object inspector palette to get the x/y coordinates of the objects before you copy, and then you can just type in those same coordinates after you paste.

Comment: I agree that it would be nice if FileMaker defaulted to pasting at the same coordinates where the copy originated from.